# I am having problems getting top 50% to work in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to program a slideshow. I have created arrows which navigate between slide however I cannot get them to center vertically on the image.

```css
.container, #img1{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    margin:auto;
}

.previous, .next {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding:8px 16px;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:rgb(73, 73, 73)
}

.next {
    right:8px;
}

.previous {
    left:8px;
}

.previous:hover, .next:hover {
    background-color:gray;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <div class='slides'>
        <div class='number' id='number'>1 / 5</div>
        <img id='img1' src='images/image1.jpg'>
        <div id='caption'>Image 1 caption</div>
    </div>
    <a href='javascript:moveToPreviousSlide()'class='previous'>Previous</a>
    <a href='javascript:moveToNextSlide()'class='next'>Next</a>
</div>
```

Comment: So you want the next & previous buttons to be on top of each other at the center of the page?

Comment: What kind of output are you expecting? It is a little unclear

Answer (score 1):

you must give you class container fixed height and put you arrow top: 55%. Try this one css code.

```
.container, #img1{
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
    margin:auto;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
}    
.previous, .next {
    ...
    top:50%;
    ...
}
Try this one. I add position relative and it start work)
```

Comment: Thank you for response however it is still not centering vertically over the image, instead it is centering in the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

Try add transform property to .previous and .next elements:

```
.previous, .next {
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Also .container may need relative positioning:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thank you that has fixed it , for some reason -50% aligned it to the bottom of the image but I have changed it to -650% and it looks about right, not sure why. Any ideas? Thanks for the reply, much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Here are some possible solutions:

```
.previous, .next {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 50;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:rgb(73, 73, 73)
}

.next {
    right: 700px;
    top: 113%;
    padding: 8px 29px 8px 29px;
}

.previous {
    left: 48%;
    top: 120%;
    padding: 8px 16px 8px 16px;
}
```

Output:

[image]

```
.container, #img1 {
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
    margin:auto;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
}

.previous, .next {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 50;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:rgb(73, 73, 73)
}

.next {
    right: 700px;
    top: 43%;
    padding: 8px 29px 8px 29px;
}

.previous {
    left: 48%;
    top: 50%;
    padding: 8px 16px 8px 16px;
}
```

Output:

[image]